# Pivoting data in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am doing a time series analysis. I have run the below code to generate random year in the dataframe as the original year did not have year values:

```
wc['Random_date'] = wc.Monthdate.apply(lambda val: f'{val} {randint(2019,2022)}') 
#Generating random year from 2019 to 2022 to create ideal conditions
```

And now I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
wc.head()
```

[image]

The ID column is the index currently, and I would like to generate a pivoted dataframe that looks like this:

| Random_date | Count_of_ID |
| --- | --- |
| Jul 3 2019 | 2 |
| Jul 4 2019 | 3 |

I do understand that aggregation will be needed to be done after I pivot the data, but the following code is not working:

```
abscount = wc.pivot(index= 'Random_date', columns= 'Random_date', values= 'ID')
```

Here is the ending part of the error that I see:

[image]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Why Jul 3 2019 return 2?

Comment: It's just an example. All I want to do is get a dataframe that shows the number of times and ID has a particular random_date in it's row. As I randomized the year, in the rows below, Jul 3 2019 may appear many times again (I don't know how many times exactly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check with

```
df['Random_date'].value_counts()
```

If need unique count

```
df.reset_index().drop_duplicates('ID')['Random_date'].value_counts()
```

Or

```
df.reset_index().groupby('Random_date')['ID'].nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I never thought I could do a value counts when I know about this function. However, now I am trying to plot it, and the new dataframe doesn't have any headers. Will add them. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Beny. I decided to go with the values counts code above instead of the groupby.  However, now I am unable to plot using the plot_df function. It says "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Count_of_abs'" whereas I have already defined the column this way:

abscount.columns = ["Counts_abs"]

Any ideas?

Comment: out = df['Random_date'].value_counts().to_frame('Counts_abs') @KaustubhMulay